# WPF MVVM binding listbox inside tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox, tabcontrol

I'm trying to create a small chat app that shows a tab control on the mainform and that will display new tabs upon message received from different users.

All the event wiring is done and working well but, visually, inside the TabItems, there is a listbox that needs to be bound to data and I get no runtime errors but the listboxes stays empty when the events are done doing their thing.

If I add a message in the loaded event of the window, I see that message on screen but still, when I receive a message, the same code doesn't seem to work.
A breakpoint in the code confrimed me that it's executing and no exceptions are being thrown.

Here's a bit of code:

```
//Executes when there's an incoming message 
[...]
public ObservableCollection<Discussion> UserDiscussionList { get; set; }
public string NewMessage { get; set; }
public Discussion CurrentDiscussion { get; set; }

public async void MessageReceived(string userName, string message)
{
     await _dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
     {
          CurrentDiscussion = UserDiscussionList[0];
          CurrentDiscussion.MessageList.Add(new MessageDetail
          {
               Message = message,
               UserName = userName
          });

          NewMessage = string.Empty; //resets the typed message property
    });
}
[...]
```

Here's my xaml:

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserDiscussionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDiscussion, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type hub:Discussion}">
                <views:DiscussionControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes I did, nothing shows up...

Comment: Do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Is `CurrentDiscussion.MessageList` an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Now I feel like a retard... Thank you for letting me realize this...

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare my MessageList as ObservableCollection<>... Doing so made everything work perfectly.